# C# and ms database - Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am building an application where when i press an button the action need to be save in a Microsoft Access Database, but when i press the button i get the error  "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" from the next part of code

```
        string dbconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source =ElevatorLog.accdb";
        string dbcommand = "insert into [Elevator] ([MovingAction],[TimeAction]) values (@movingaction, @timeaction)";
        string timeaction = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();


        listBox1.Items.Add(movingaction + "\t\t" + timeaction + "\t\t");

        OleDbConnection conn_db = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection);
        OleDbCommand comm_insert = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn_db);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter_insert = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm_insert);
        comm_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeaction", timeaction);
        comm_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movingaction", movingaction);

        conn_db.Open();

        comm_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn_db.Close();
```

Comment: `timeaction` must be DateTime, not string. `var timeaction = DateTime.Now;` Voting to close as typo. You should also put `comm_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movingaction", movingaction);` **above** the other `AddWithValue` call.

Comment: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: Your data types are not correct as the message says. Do not use AddWithValue but Add. adapter_insert has no function in your code. And also use using blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your datatypes are but guessing partially from code:

```
string dbconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source =ElevatorLog.accdb";
string dbcommand = @"insert into [Elevator] 
       ([MovingAction],[TimeAction]) 
       values 
       (@movingaction, @timeaction)";


//?        listBox1.Items.Add(movingaction + "\t\t" + timeaction + "\t\t");

using (OleDbConnection conn_db = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection))
using (OleDbCommand comm_insert = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn_db))
{
   comm_insert.Parameters.Add("@movingaction", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = movingaction; // not sure if this is DateTime
   comm_insert.Parameters.Add("@timeaction", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTime.Now;

  conn_db.Open();
  comm_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
  conn_db.Close();
}
```

PS: Just a suggestion, choose a better database like postgreSQL, MS SQL, MySQL, SQLite ...